# Page Not Posting Back Data When Using Fluent Automation to Click Submit

Tags: asp.net, fluentautomation

I am automating some tests on an ASP.NET form with Fluent Automation.  When the program clicks the submit button, the page refreshes and the fields are cleared of data.

I have tried using a link button and an ASP button control for this and get the same results with either of them.

I am using the following code to trigger the click:

I.Click([MYBUTTON]);

Anyone have a suggestion as to why my automated button click is not firing a proper postback?

Comment: There can be any number of reasons this behavior would occur but I'm highly skeptical that its related to FluentAutomation.

You've also given very little to go on to help diagnose this issue. Please add more details.

Answer (score 1):

After doing further debugging, it turns out that the Fluent Automation tests were working as they should.

I also have Glimpse installed on my site for testing.  With Glimpse disabled, my page post backs were not working properly.  I removed Glimpse from the site and my tests are working as expected.